# SpriteKit SKTexture mipmap doesn't work

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, mipmaps, sktexture

I cannot figure it out how to apply mipmaps for SKTexture texture. I'm using XCode 8.2.1 with Swift.

Here is my method:

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    logo = childNode(withName: "logo") as! SKSpriteNode
    let texture: SKTexture! = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "logo")
    texture.usesMipmaps = true
    logo.texture = texture
}
```

I use sample image png 512*512 size (pot both)
Full size it looks like this:
[image: full size image]

Then I want to decrease its size to 128*128 pixels

[image: decrease size]

And here is the output with mipmapping enabled:
[image: mipmapping enabled output 128*128]

And for example output without mipmapping (only default linear filtering)[image: without mipmapping]

They both looks the same. So I think mipmaps didn't apply. Help me please, I've spent 3 days trying solve this problem.

**UPD:**
As [Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109038/confused) told me, I made all job in code. Created texture with mipmaping enabled, assign it to SKSpriteNode and then perform scaling by scale method or action.

```
let texture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "logo")
texture.usesMipmaps = true
logo = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: texture)
logo.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.addChild(logo)
//logo.scale(to: CGSize(width: 128, height: 128))
let scaleAction = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: 128, height: 128), duration: 1)
    logo.run(scaleAction)
```

Result is the same:
[image]

Comment: You're right. They are exactly the same. I dropped them into Photoshop and did a Difference blend. The one without mipmapping is one pixel to the left of where it should be, in your screenshot, but once that's corrected, these are identical.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't surprise, at all, if the Xcode SpriteKit Scene Editor is doing the resizing of your texture before the mipmapping is activated by your code. Meaning a 128x128 version of your texture has mipmapping on, because that's what Xcode and SpriteKit SceneEditor have conspired to store as a texture.

So instead of setting the scale in the Scene Editor, after turning on mipMapping in your code, use this to scale the SKSpriteNode:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1645445-scale

and/or experiment with the SKAction scaling operations:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction

In this way you can be absolutely sure that the sequence of events is

1. Turn on mipmapping
2. Perform Scaling

And hopefully this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help. Look at UPD above.

Comment: DOH! What devices have you tested this on?

Comment: Tested on my mac and iOS Simulators.

Comment: argh. Ok. You're going to definitely want to test on devices. There's a good chance that GPU optimisations (of which mipmapping is one) aren't happening in the simulators.

Comment: Ok, maybe Simulators is not the best case for such testing, but I think mipmapping should work on macOS 10.12.3

Comment: I wouldn't count on anything like that to be true. The lack of consistency in SpriteKit is its only consistency.

Comment: Good answer Confused. @widesteppe Have you tried also with `override func didMove(to view: SKView) {` instead of `override func sceneDidLoad() {`